# See if a type variable represents a superclass of a given Class

Tags: java, reflection, types, casting

Given a class

```
class EnvironmentHolder<V> {
    protected Map<String,V> environment;

    // Get the Type of V via Google's GSon library; this part
    // works okay
    protected final Type VALUE_TYPE = new TypeToken<V>() {}.getType();

    ...

    public void importEnvironment(Class aClass) {
        // NEEDS AN IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}
```

where `V` is some reference type, I'm trying to collect all of the
static members of `aClass` which are "assignable to" a class of type
`V` — that is, those which are subclasses, implementations of, or the
same class as `V`.

How do I do this? I'd like to use the following implementation for `importEnvironment`:

```
for (Field field : aClass.getFields()) {
    ((Class) V).isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
}
```

I see that `Class` is indeed an implementer of [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html), but I'm not
sure how to perform a cast safely. (`Type` also encompasses
non-reference types, which are not `Class`es.)

NB: *Please* don't say, "Type erasure precludes doing this at runtime"
until you have thought it through. A fair number of questions have that as a virtually automatic response, which would seem to imply that a reflection API is impossible to implement in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: "Get the Type of V using Google's Guava library; this part works okay" - Are you sure? The point of creating the anonymous subclass is to have the type information directly coded into it. It was my understanding that if you put a generic type V in here, you lose the purpose of TypeToken.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! I meant Gson. Well, it seems to work, anyway; but perhaps I'm missing something. This is the official [recommendation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#collections-examples) of Gson.

Comment: Absolutely, but I don't think anywhere in their examples will you see them instantiate a TypeToken with a generic type (as you did with `TypeToken<V>`). In the docs you cite, they have `TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>` for a reason - they would never have `TypeToken<Collection<T>>`, because TypeToken would be useless. Essentially, TypeToken only works if its instantiated with non-generic types.

Comment: @nickb I think I finally understand what you're getting at. The `toString()` value of `VALUE_TYPE` is literally `V`; it is not the *specific* type that `V` is instantiated to. Oh, well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with your existing code because of type erasure: you don't know what `V` is at runtime.

You will need an instance of `Class<V>`, so you can say:

```
clazz.isAssignableFrom(field.getType());
```

You can either pass this as a construction-time parameter of `EnvironmentVariable<V>`, or pass it as another parameter of `importEnvironment`. I'd say the former is more convenient, since you just have to do this once, rather than whenever you invoke `importEnvironment`.

```
class EnvironmentHolder<V> {
    private final Class<V> clazz;

    EnvironmentHolder(Class<V> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void importEnvironment(Class<?> aClass) {
        for (Field field : aClass.getFields()) {
            if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you could also do it by passing in (and storing) an instance of `TypeToken<V>` - which might be more convenient if `V` is itself a generic type. However, as @nickb notes, you actually need to pass in that instance; you can't rely upon generics to create it.

Also note the `<?>` on `Class<?> aClass` - there is no reason to use a raw type here.